# How to add multiple dynamic ip v4/v6 using netplan for both wired and wireless network?

Tags: netplan

Primarily, I need to add multiple IP addresses(v6-only) to both wired and wireless interfaces. I don't have static IP addresses and only acquiring my IPv6 address through Flet's IPv6 service, I guess it is considered as DHCP for IPv6(?).

Here's my  /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml file:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                MyHomeWifi:
                    password: MyHomeWifiPassword
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```

**Update**

I have both Ubuntu 20.10 server(arm64, RPi4) and Ubuntu 20.04 desktop(amd64). I'll most likely implement it only on Ubuntu servers(I ordered another RPi4 device).

Comment: @guiverc I updated my post and included the versions of Ubuntu I'm using. But most likely, I'll stick on LTS servers later to simulate a live-environment while developing my server app.

Comment: Right below your `dhcp4: true` lines add a `dhcp6: true`.  You should get the IPv6 IP addresses if your network cards are on the same network as your DHCPv6 server / router.  Kind of hard to say though since we can't see how your network layout is.

Comment: @Terrance I only have one of each network devices. One ethernet and one wlan.

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  Add one `dhcp6: true` to each section for your ethernet and your wlan.